# Importing NDK project into eclipse creates multiple projects

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, eclipse-juno

I am trying to `import` the [**Linephone**](http://www.linphone.org/eng/download/)  project into eclipse, and `eclipse is showing multiple projects instead of just one project`.

[image]

I have tried creating a new working set but it didn't solve the problem.

The eclipse release version is `Juno`, and the [ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) version is 20.0.3.

Why is it splitting the project into different projects, how can I `import the project into a single project` ?

Comment: Some projects seam to be test projects, other NDK projects. Are you sure all are required? If you are not sure as the developer(s).

Comment: Yes they are all required, but in a previous eclipse release it used to work but I don't remember which one.

Answer (score 1):

`org.linphone.LinphoneLauncherActivity` seems to be the main project. Rest of them seems to be dependancies/tests. You will have to import all the projects and then add the dependencies to `LinphoneLauncherActivity` project until no dependecy errors are shown in the project(red warning sign)